# Jenkins proxy error

Tags: jenkins

Today we got the following error from one of the servers where Jenkins instance

```
Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /abarjigs/.
```

To look for the error we got into the service manager and observe how much memory this jenkins instance is craving. We found that it is eating up more than allocated and suspected that the service is killed, eventually the server not being available.

We are not sure though if this is indeed the reason behind this proxy error. Anyway, we allocated more memory to the jenkins instance and each time we encountered this type of error, we saw from Windows service manager that java.exe is taking more memory than allocated.

Do you think we are looking into the problem properly ? Where else we should look into as well ?

Comment: where exactly do you see this error message?

Comment: It shows up on the browser as the jenkins service is unavailable due to shutdown

Comment: Is it possible to access the log file that describes the reason behind jenkins service going down?